# IndexError: index 43 is out of bounds, but there is no error in column entries?

Tags: python, arrays, index-error

I'm working on a script to make a table with only the first 44 lines of data from another file being called in and adding 2 magnitudes.

```
size = 45
JH_syn = np.zeros(size)
HK_syn = np.zeros(size)
for i in range(size):
    fit_data = ascii.read('pickles_mag_complete.txt', data_start = 1, data_end = 44)
    fn = fit_data[0][:]
    spec_type = fit_data[1][:]
    magJ = fit_data[10][:]
    magH = fit_data[11][:]
    magK = fit_data[12][:]
    # Calculating J-H and H-K difference from fits-based data:
    JH_syn[i] = magJ[i] - magH[i]
    JH_syn[i] = float("%.3f" % JH_syn[i])
    HK_syn[i] = magH[i] - magK[i]
    HK_syn[i] = float("%.3f" % HK_syn[i])
    # J-H and H-K from 2MASS table:
    JH_pap = np.array([-0.7, -1, -0.15, -1, -1, -1, -0.06, -0.04, -0.01, -1,
                   0.03, 0.06, 0.09, 0.12, 0.18, 0, -1, 0, 0.23, 0, 0, 0.26, 0,
                   0, 0.28, 0.30, 0, 0, 0.34, 0.39, 0, 0, 0.44, 0.49, 0.54, 0.59,
                   0.64, 0.65, 0.64, 0.63, -1, 0.60, 0.56, 0.60, 0.63])
   HK_pap = np.array([-0.06, -1, -0.05, -1, -1, -1, -0.02, -1, 0.01, 0.02, -1, 0.035, 
                   0.04, 0.045, 0.05, 0.055, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0.07, 0, 0, 0.075, 0.08,
                  0, 0, 0.09, 0.10, 0, 0.11, 0.12, 0.135, 0.145, 0.16, 0.18, 0.20,
                  0.23, -1, 0.245, 0.28, 0.34, 0.38])
   # Print screen to double check if it does what it needs to do correctly:
   print(i, fn[i], spec_type[i], JH_syn[i], JH_pap[i], HK_syn[i], HK_pap[i])

## Now finally creating the table to be put in the output file: 
data = Table()
data['FileName'] = fn
data['Spectra Type'] = spec_type
data['(J-H)_synphot'] = JH_syn
data['(J-H)_0'] = JH_pap
data['(H-K)_synphot'] = HK_syn
data['(H-K)_0'] = HK_pap
## Writing to a .txt file:
ascii.write(data, 'pickle_known_color_mag.txt', overwrite=True)
```

When I uncomment the print([i], fn[i]...) statement, I get a ValueError: for inconsistent column lengths but when I comment it, I get this error: IndexError: index 43 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 43 for the JH_syn[i] calculation. The column lengths are correct, I'm just not sure why I'm getting this error or how to fix it.

Comment: `JH_syn[i] = float("%.3f" % JH_syn[i])` -- what do you think you're doing with that?  You adjust the decimal places when you PRINT the data, not in the actual computation.

Comment: The code as you have posted it has incorrect indentation; the `HK_pap` line and the `print` are not lined up with the rest of the loop.  Please double-check that.

Comment: If those are numpy arrays, then you should just do `JH_syn = magJ - magH` once the loop is over.  Don't do it element by element.

Comment: For the float comment, I'm just adjusting the decimals as the value gets computed in the loop. The indentation was probably because of the tabbing here, the indentations are correct in my script. Yes those are numpy arrays, but I need to calculate the difference for each element -- that's why I have it that way. If I do it at the end, wouldn't it only calculate one value and not all 44?

Comment: No!!!  That's the beauty of numpy.  That expression does element-wise matrix subtraction and returns an array the same size as its input. What I was trying to say is that adjusting decimals before doing arithmetic is always a bad idea.  Humans are the only ones who care about decimals, so leave the numbers with full precision, and use formatting when you PRINT the value to make it pretty for humans.

Comment: Adding JH_syn and HK_syn to the end of the loop does not work -- I have to calculate those values iteration by iteration since magJ, magH, and magK are all from the file I'm reading and looping through -- it just gives me 0's if it's left outside the loop

Comment: How large are `JH_syn` and `HK_syn`?  You're reading 43 lines.  And aren't you reading the same 43 lines every time?

Comment: 44, but it should be reading 44 lines not 43. It's like it's skipping the first line that I want to be read -- I'm actually having a similar issue again since i'm trying to rewrite the script entirely and it's an ongoing theme

Comment: Well, `JH_syn` is not being indexed by the number of lines in the file.  You're reading those (same) 44 lines 45 times, and it's the `i` loop variable that indexes `JH_syn`.